# ParserError en Solidity

Tags: solidity

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de contratos inteligentes.. y me encuentro atorado en esta línea de código, pues según he observado no estoy cumpliendo con las instrucciones paso a paso y evidentemente tengo un error que no detecto.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <=0.9.0;

interface AggregatorV3Interface {

  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

  function description() external view returns (string memory);

  function version()external view returns (uint256);

  // getRoundData and latestRoundData should both raise "No data present"
  // if they do not have data to report, instead of returning unset values
  // which could be misinterpreted as actual reported values.

  function getRoundData(uint80 _roundId)
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt, uint256 updatedAt, uint80 answeredInRound);

  function latestRoundData() external view returns (uint80 roundId, int256 answer; uint256 startedAt, uint256 updatedAt, uint80 answeredInRound);

}

contract FundMe {
    
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    
    //Función que permite realizar pagos.. 
    function fund() public payable{
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
    
    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256);
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        return priceFeed.version();
}
```

---

Ya di con el error, no abrí las llaves para indicarle al método las intrucciones..

Comment: Por favor, la solución va en el campo Respuesta, abajo. Así otros sabrán cuál es la solución. E, idealmente, lleva un ejemplo de cómo esa descripción de la solución aplica al código que compartiste en la pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias por las recomendaciones, es mi primer consulta y no estaba al tanto de esto que me comentas.. Saludos..